# Why do lein's control keys work for me using lein1, but not lein2?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've successfully upgraded to lein2, and have run `lein repl` successfully. I use VanDyke's SecureCrt to log into my Ubuntu 12.04 workstation. I have not changed any terminal settings, and did not have the following problem with lein 1.x.

When I went to use my usual bash command line keys like CTRL+A, CTRL+E, and CTRL+C, none of those keys worked.

What do I need to do to enable these CTRL keys?

Following the install instructions, I saved my original lein as lein1. I've tried that, and the control keys work, as noted above.

I've tried installing lein2 for a new user, instead of an upgrade, and the control key problem persists. I've also tried this on CentOS and Ubuntu systems. The same behavior exists.

Here is the output from stty -a

speed 38400 baud; rows 42; columns 159; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ; eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
cnorton@steamboy:~/projects/clojure/wtr-usage1$

Here is the output from new lein:

```
nREPL server started on port 52310
REPL-y 0.1.9
Clojure 1.4.0
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Commands: (user/help)
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
          (user/sourcery function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Examples from clojuredocs.org: [clojuredocs or cdoc]
          (user/clojuredocs name-here)
          (user/clojuredocs "ns-here" "name-here")
wtr-usage1.core=>
```

Are there any directories or files that should be cleaned up between lein 1 and 2? I have no plugins, so did not do any of that part of the upgrade.

I have continued to work on this problem, and performed the following diagnostic tests:

1) I ran the following command

```
java -cp target/jline-2.11-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar:target/jline-2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar -Djline.internal.Log.debug=true jline.example.Example none
```

in a cloned jline2 directory. The control keys did not work.

2) I ran the following command

`export JLINE_LOGGING=trace && lein trampoline run`

in a cloned -- `git clone git://github.com/trptcolin/reply.git` -- reply directory. The control keys worked. It was suggested to me that I create an [issue](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/79) on github, which I did.

Comment: I will gladly post more information about my workstation, and I'll go try this on a non Ubuntu system for further testing. I know there's something I'm missing to fix as part of the lein1 to lein2 upgrade.

Comment: Thanks to whomever upvoted this. I don't know why it was ever downvoted. I posted everything but the kitchen sink, and kept editing the original post to reflect the testing I did from answers that were helpful but did not solve the problem. Finally, I sought help outside SO, working with someone involved with leiningen, who provided me the answers I was seeking. Those answers were tackling my installation using diagnostics. In the end it was decided to post an issue against leiningen. I edited the OP with the results of those diagnostic tests to make the question as complete as possible.

Comment: There is a fix for this, which I will try soon. https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/pull/1057 If this works, I'll edit the OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestion of  A. Webb I am posting my github issue #79 for jline as an answer. This works with term, but not with my SecureCrt. SecureCrt had no problems with lein1.

---

Control Keys Don't Work and Missing ~/.jline.rc file

No milestone
No one is assigned

(I have gone ahead and created a ~/.jline.rc containing jline.terminal=auto since writing this issue.)
My issue is my control keys do not work, and what can I do to work around this issue.

Here is a description of what I've done.

I am running

java -cp target/jline-2.11-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar:target/jline-2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar -Djline.internal.Log.debug=true jline.example.Example none

in my ~/jline2 directory, where I installed jline2. My control keys (ctrl+a, ctrl+e, ctrl+u and Backspace) do not work.

I am logging into an Ubuntu 12.04 system with bash as the shell and using a VanDyke SecureCrt terminal emulator product. I have made no recent settings changes to my emulator.

First, I notice I have no ~/.jline.rc file
[DEBUG] Loading properties from: file:/home/cnorton/.jline.rc
[DEBUG] Unable to read configuration from: file:/home/cnorton/.jline.rc
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cnorton/.jline.rc (No such file or directory)

After the stack trace, here is the rest of the output.

[DEBUG] Creating terminal; type=auto
[DEBUG] Config: speed 38400 baud; rows 34; columns 117; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke

[DEBUG] Created Terminal: jline.UnixTerminal@1d520c4
[DEBUG] Registering shutdown-hook: Thread[JLine Shutdown Hook,5,main]
[DEBUG] Adding shutdown-hook task: jline.TerminalSupport$1@1e9cb75
[DEBUG] Ansi supported: true
[DEBUG] Echo enabled: false
[DEBUG] NonBlockingInputStream start
[DEBUG] Loaded user configuration: file:/home/cnorton/.inputrc
prompt> [DEBUG] Running all shutdown-hook tasks
[DEBUG] Running task: jline.TerminalSupport$1@1e9cb75
[DEBUG] Removing shutdown-hook: Thread[JLine Shutdown Hook,5,main]

Here is some more debugging output from running

export JLINE_LOGGING=trace && lein trampoline run
in a cloned directory
git clone git://github.com/trptcolin/reply.git
Please note the control keys work.

cnorton@steamboy:~/reply$ export JLINE_LOGGING=trace && lein trampoline run
REPL-y 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT
Clojure 1.4.0
Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Commands: (user/help)
Docs: (doc function-name-here)
(find-doc "part-of-name-here")
Source: (source function-name-here)
(user/sourcery function-name-here)
Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Examples from clojuredocs.org: clojuredocs or cdoc
(user/clojuredocs "ns-here" "name-here")
[DEBUG] Loading properties from: file:/home/cnorton/.jline.rc
[DEBUG] Loaded properties:
[DEBUG] jline.terminal=unix
[TRACE]
java.lang.Throwable: CREATE MARKER
at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:50)
at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
at jline.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:226)
at jline.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:218)
at jline.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:210)
at reply.reader.simple_jline$setup_console_reader.invoke(simple_jline.clj:39)
at reply.reader.simple_jline$get_input_line.invoke(simple_jline.clj:74)
at reply.reader.simple_jline$safe_read_line$fn__941.invoke(simple_jline.clj:101)
at clojure.lang.Atom.swap(Atom.java:37)
at clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:2108)
at reply.reader.simple_jline$safe_read_line.invoke(simple_jline.clj:99)
at reply.eval_modes.nrepl$safe_read_line.invoke(nrepl.clj:55)
at reply.eval_modes.nrepl$parsed_forms.invoke(nrepl.clj:88)
at reply.eval_modes.nrepl$run_repl.invoke(nrepl.clj:139)
at reply.eval_modes.nrepl$main.invoke(nrepl.clj:227)
at reply.main$launch_nrepl$fn__3187.invoke(main.clj:63)
at clojure.core$with_redefs_fn.invoke(core.clj:6585)
at reply.main$launch_nrepl.invoke(main.clj:62)
at reply.main$launch.invoke(main.clj:79)
at reply.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:89)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:411)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at reply.ReplyMain.main(ReplyMain.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeStaticMethod(Reflector.java:207)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeStaticMethod(Reflector.java:200)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeStaticMethod(Reflector.java:207)
at user$eval5.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

[DEBUG] Creating terminal; type=unix
[TRACE] Running: [sh,-c,stty -a < /dev/tty]
[TRACE] Result: speed 38400 baud; rows 34; columns 117; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke

[DEBUG] Config: speed 38400 baud; rows 34; columns 117; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke

[DEBUG] Created Terminal: jline.UnixTerminal@74a7af
[DEBUG] Registering shutdown-hook: Thread[JLine Shutdown Hook,5,main]
[DEBUG] Adding shutdown-hook task: jline.TerminalSupport$1@183e6d4
[DEBUG] Ansi supported: true
[TRACE] Running: [sh,-c,stty -icanon min 1 -icrnl -inlcr < /dev/tty]
[TRACE] Result:
[TRACE] Running: [sh,-c,stty -echo < /dev/tty]
[TRACE] Result:
[DEBUG] Echo enabled: false
[DEBUG] NonBlockingInputStream start
[DEBUG] Loaded user configuration: file:/home/cnorton/.inputrc
[TRACE] Loading history from: /home/cnorton/.jline-reply.history
user=> [TRACE] Running: [sh,-c,stty intr undef < /dev/tty]
[TRACE] Result:
[TRACE] Keystroke: 1
[TRACE] Binding: BEGINNING_OF_LINE
[TRACE] Keystroke: 5
[TRACE] Binding: END_OF_LINE
[TRACE] Keystroke: 21
[TRACE] Binding: UNIX_LINE_DISCARD
[TRACE] Keystroke: 127
[TRACE] Binding: BACKWARD_DELETE_CHAR

---

Comment: And if I set SecureCrt to Linux Terminal from VT100 terminal, this works. Most of my Informx 4GL applications need VT100 terminals.

Answer (score 1):

That's not supposed to happen. Try executing `set -o emacs` in bash, but there shouldn't be anything in the lein script to disable it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it's still disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling leiningen. `lein2 repl` on my configuration launches REPL-y, it looks like this:

```
% lein2 repl
Downloading Leiningen to /home/dpx-infinity/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.0.0-standalone.jar now...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.6M  100 12.6M    0     0  93665      0  0:02:21  0:02:21 --:--:-- 91018
nREPL server started on port 47543
REPL-y 0.1.9
Clojure 1.4.0
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Commands: (user/help)
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
          (user/sourcery function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Examples from clojuredocs.org: [clojuredocs or cdoc]
          (user/clojuredocs name-here)
          (user/clojuredocs "ns-here" "name-here")
user=>
```

REPL-y has all usual editing commands. If you're not getting this, then there should be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: Re-installed. Still does not work. cnorton@steamboy:~/projects/clojure/wtr-usage1$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 48953
REPL-y 0.1.9 
Clojure 1.4.0  My lein is called lein, not lein2. It's installed  locally in my ~/bin directory. What are some of the editing commands other than Backspace, CTRL+A, and so on? I'll try one of them.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, well, all standard emacs commands are working: ctrl+a, ctrl+e, ctrl+f, ctrl+b, alt+f, alt+b, ctrl+d, alt+d etc. Since it appears that REPL-y is launched normally, this seems to be a problem with your terminal emulator. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about SecureCrt, so I cannot help here. Maybe these combinations clash with SecureCrt own shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, but my control keys work fine lein1. I'm trying to find out the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to test new fresh lein installation in new fresh environment:

1. Create new user: `sudo useradd -m testlein`
2. Switch to new user: `sudo su - testlein`
3. Get latest lein2: `wget https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein`
4. Set `execute` permission: `chmod +x lein`
5. Install lein: `./lein`
6. Run repl: `./lein repl`

After that try commands ctrl-a/e/... .

P.S. I don't know how did you install java in your system. Perhaps you should set up java in new user environment before step 5.

Comment: Performed these steps with same results. No control keys.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Did you try other terminal emulators?

Comment: No, but I'll try term on Monday sitting at my console, which I can't from home. The emulator has not changed. lein has. lein2 builds fine; only the control keys don't work.

Comment: This works in term; now I've got to find out what the differences are between SecureCrt and term. My emulator settings did not change, but I migrated from lein1 to lein2. So some setting in the emulator needs to change, but why?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to [problems with JLine on Cygwin](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1822900&group_id=64033&atid=506056). Trying the same workaround your system is worth a shot.

Edit the lein script starting about line 284 to the following; added lines are indicated with a `->`.

```
    export TRAMPOLINE_FILE

->  stty -icanon min 1 -echo

    "$LEIN_JAVA_CMD" \
        -client -XX:+TieredCompilation \
        "${BOOTCLASSPATH[@]}" \
        $LEIN_JVM_OPTS \
        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
->      -Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal \      
        -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false \
        -Dleiningen.original.pwd="$ORIGINAL_PWD" \
        -Dleiningen.script="$SCRIPT" \
        -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main "$@"

->  stty icanon echo

    EXIT_CODE=$?
```

Comment: Tried with errors. I'll post them at the end of my post. What do I need to add?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus You have a typo. Error output says `-icannon`, input switch is `-icanon`. Too many `n`s.

Comment: The errors went away after I deleted the lein jar and re-did self-install. The problem persists, however.

Comment: I accepted it, because you answered as I requested. I wanted help debugging the problem, which you provided. Whatever this problem is, I spent some time last week going over things step by step with someone on the lein mailing list, sending results back and forth. That's what lead to the issue put on github under jline.

Comment: The lein I depend on ~/bin/lein did not get overwritten, and shows up as the lein I use in `which lein`. The edits you gave me are in there. Another test would be I'd take your edits out, and keep the terminal a "Linux" terminal (in SecureCrt) http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html